# How to write Angularjs code without module and controller as JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Please help to explain me, how to write angularjs version 1 without module
or controller.

I used to use JQuery code as above, May you please help to update my Jquery source code to Angularjs version 1. My source code is:

```
function checkPermission(){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'some url her...',
      dataType: 'json',
      catche: false,
      success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
          console.log(result);
      }
 });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  checkPermission();
});
$(document).on('click',function(event){

  console.log(".....");
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Actually you're asking something like: "How to write in Angularjs without Angularjs".

Answer (score 0):

What you ask isn't possible, questions is what i want from `angularjs` without `module` and `controller` or other options this framework have?

`Angularjs` is powerful framework which if you learn it you will forget the `jQuery` or at least you will use 1% of it in your applications.

in other language `angularjs` without `module`, `service`, `factory` and a lot of other features Equal to `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular.js you're going to need a module and controller. If you want it look like JQuery, use JQuery instead.

To write your app as an angular application, after importing the JavaScript you need to declare the module that you will be using. In simple applications like yours it's normal to do this on the html element. Everything inside the html tags is your app.

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
```

This app must be defined in your JavaScript.

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
```

Next, you need to define the controller which will hold your custom code. There's no getting around this if you want to use Angular.js. The controller is attached to an element and everything within it is handled by the controller. I've also added a button to run your on click event.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="onClick()">Click me</button>
</body>
```

The controller is added to your app in the JavaScript. I've needed to inject the $http module in order to make http requests.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.post('some url here...', {body: 'body data'})
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })

  $scope.onClick = function () {
    console.log('.....');
  }
});
```

Here's a working demo:

https://embed.plnkr.co/1ZUdAY58loT3dYJLXVNR/

This is the simplest working example of your code running as an angular app. I suggest you go through a tutorial to learn the basics. Although W3schools gets a bad reputation, their Angularjs tutorial is really good at getting the hang of the basics:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

Unless there is a specific reason why you need Angularjs you should consider learning Angular instead. Follow the "Get Started" instructions here: https://angular.io/

Comment: Thank Geraint Anderson for your detail explation